# Inrush current limiting circuit

Tags: current, current-limiting, power-factor-correction

For my boost PFC design that I am currentely working on, I need a current limiting circuit for the capacitor inrush current in start up, the widely used circuit in this type of applications cases is shown in this figure

[image]

The relay is turned on after some miliseconds when the capacitor is fully charged and the diode is reversed baised

My question: how can I determine the amount of current drown by the capacitor and more importantly, on what criteria will I choose the diode and the NTC resistor on and based on what?

Thank you very much.

Comment: .Change your circuit .C1 charges rapidly through L1 saturating it and blowing D5.It it safer to put your relay and NTC on the AC side.

Comment: You either calculate or simulate it. I would use 10 ohm NTC as a starting point.